# Find a credit card within a string

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a way to detect a credit card within a string using C#. Regex is a possibility. I do not want to detect if a string is a credit card.

For example

```
string text = "Hi mum, here is my credit card 1234-1234-1223-1234. Don't tell anyone";
bool result = TextContainsCreditCard(text);
if (result)
  throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't give people your credit card!");
```

Comment: totally unclear for me.

Comment: Why don't you use `string.contains` possibilities?

Comment: A sequence of 16+ digits beginning 4/5/6 that pass the luhn (mod10) test

Comment: Does String.Contains work with a regex? A credit card can be various formats.

Comment: Do you want - as the only number separator, or could it use other symbols?

Comment: Replace whitespace/- use a regex to capture ([456]\d{16,25}), test matches with luhn

Comment: I think potentially spaces or - could also be separator. This is a free text field.

Comment: RegEx would be the way to go

Comment: Is this sufficient? `text.Contains("credit card")` ;-)

Comment: Is this helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768/how-do-you-detect-credit-card-type-based-on-number ?

Comment: Make a list of all credit card formats you want to check against. Make a regex for each format. Possibly combine regexes. Check string against all of them. Perform additional tests (luhn).

Comment: Is the number in this case *always* formatted like that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463252/creditcard-verification-with-regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regex like

```
(\d{4}[\s-]?){4}
```

And put any chars you want as separator to `[\s-]` now they are only space and minus

And this allows separators in any position `(\d[\s-]?){16}` like `1 2341234-12341 234`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your separator is ONLY spaces or -, then the regex to detect the credit card would be

```
([0-9]{4}(-| )){3}[0-9]{4}
```

or maybe there are shorter or better options.

Answer (score 0):

I have drafted this algorithm (would place as comment only it would be badly formatted)

1. Split string on (-)
2. See if string contains numeric values.
3. See if there are 4+ parts
4. See if parts[0] + parts[1] (i.e. four in a row)
5. If so, return true, if not, return false?

Comment: Presumably not everyone will neatly delimit their card numbers

Comment: I'm not great with implementation, but @AlexK. I think checking if there are 16 digits, and ensuring that they form a credit card, is pretty difficult to master a 'perfect' algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regex to do it

```
(\d{4}-?){4}
```

Here is the sample output with grep.

```
$ echo "Hi mum, here is my credit card 1234-1234-1223-1234. Don't tell anyone"|grep -Po "(\d{4}-?){4}"
1234-1234-1223-1234
```